# avcodec_decode_video2 returns positive number when got_picture_ptr is 0

Tags: video, ffmpeg

According to the documentation: [here](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.2/group__lavc__decoding.html#ga3ac51525b7ad8bca4ced9f3446e96532), `avcodec_decode_video2` should return 0 if no frame could be decompressed. The `got_picture_ptr` should also be set to zero if no frame could be decompressed.

I ran this function on a h264 video and I got positive return value while the `got_picture_ptr`  was set to 0. Maybe that the documentation is not updated ?

Answer (score 2):

The document you pointed to does not say it should return 0. It reads `On error a negative value is returned, otherwise the number of bytes used or zero if no frame could be decompressed.`

This falls into the `number of bytes used` category. Just because bytes were used, doesn't mean a frame is ready. For example B frames are out of order. Meaning that it was decoded, but can be render until more are decoded.